# Merge multiple tables into one table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to merge 3 tables into one only to get full data with conditions below

- merge 3 tables [test1], [test2], [test3] into one table [test]
- If when merging, if a column is blank select from another table
- Col1 exists in all 3 tables

Here is my example code to merge from table 2 into test.

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[test] a
USING [dbo].[test2] b ON a.col1 = b.col1

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET col1 = b.col1,
        col2 = b.col2,
        col3 = b.col3,
        col4 = b.col4
    WHERE col1 = '' OR col2 = '' OR col3 = '' OR col4 = '';
```

It get errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: You probably want to add to the matched part (e.g. `when matched and a.col1 = '' or a.col2 = ''  ...`) assuming you're updating where col1 in test is blank

Comment: Why are updating the main table ? instead of inserting non null values from the 3 tables ?

Comment: @SanalSunny I think it's the same.

Comment: @ZLK i think the error syntax is before where clause..

Comment: The error is because you can't put a where clause there like that. I told you a work-around that is effectively the same. Remove the where clause and add `AND ...` to the `WHEN MATCHED` part.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the COALESCE function rather than using the where condition. The COALESCE function takes the next value in case there is a NULL is encountered.

```
    Merge into [dbo].[test] a   
    using [dbo].[test2] b
    on a.col1 = b.col1
    when matched then
    update
    set col2 = COALESCE(a.col2, b.col2),
    col3 = COALESCE(a.col3, b.col3),
    col4 = COALESCE(a.col4, b.col4);
```

So in the modified code, if the Table [dbo].[test] col2 is Null then it takes the value from [dbo].[test2]. Since you will be using COALESCE, you will be able to merge any number of values.

Comment: It works when values is NULL, but when value is '' or ' '. How could we use?

Comment: In that scenario the CASE WHEN statement is to be used. Please replace COALESCE(a.col2, b.col2) with CASE WHEN a.col2 = '' THEN  b.col2 END

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the table Structure.

you can use 
`UNION ALL` Operator follow this link.

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/union.php

OR mixture of `INNER JOIN` with `UPDATE` statement combining the condition on `WHERE` clause

Comment: You should check your table structure.